# Jquery Fullpage - Disable scroll to intermediate slide

Tags: jquery, plugins, fullpage.js

I'm using JQuery [Fullpage plugin](http://www.alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) in a website but I need it to only allow scroll to the first slide of each section, i.e., if I'm in section 1 slide 2 and scroll down, it'll go to section 2 slide 1, but if I scroll up it'll take me to section 1 slide 2.

Is there any way to force it to always take me to slide 1 of each section, despite having scrolled up/down from any other slide of the previous/next section?

Thanks.

Comment: try using `onSlideLeave` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fullPage.js doesn't provide such an option.

Feel free to request a plugin customization [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/#contact-page).